# C# Global method accessible to all services

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have lots of services which fetch and manipulate data in my project.

I would like to access a method from every service which essentially queries a log table to get the creator / last editor of an entity.

What would be the best way to inject / reference this method?

For example, in my SalesOrderService, I have the following method:

```
public void GetSalesOrder(int salesOrderId)
    {
        SalesOrder salesOrder = _context.SalesOrder.Where(o => o.SalesOrderId == salesOrderId).FirstOrDefault();
        //Insert into my view model here
    CreatedBy = GetCreator("SalesOrder",salesOrderId);

    }
```

How would I generate and reference the service which queries the log with the GetCreator method?

Comment: Which IoC container are you using?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What you're wanting to do is unclear.

Comment: One solution to simplify task like this, but still allow a high degree of customisation is to use T4 scripts to generate the context from the data model classes, using attributes and interface conventions to effectively "fill in the blanks"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the affected tables either inherit from a single base class, or implement the same interface then you could either use a concrete method on the base class or extension methods so that you can write the implementation once, but use it fluently.

> Some tasks like Audit tracking in EF can be implemented using naming conventions alone, however even when you will use conventions to execute the logic, you should still use Interfaces to enforce the conventions, turning them into rules, instead of general guidelines.

```
public interface IAudiObject
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
public static User GetCreator(this IAuditObject record)
{
    // use the record.Id to resolve the user info
    // resolve the tablename either from the Table attribute on the record definition or the recrod.GetType().Name.
}
partial class SalesOrder : IAudiObject
{
    // This class doesn't follow the convention of Id for the key name, we can still implement the interface explicitly:
    int IAudiObject.Id { get => this.SalesOrderId; set => this.SalesOrderId = value; }
}
```

Usage Example

```
public void GetSalesOrder(int salesOrderId)
{
    SalesOrder salesOrder = _context.SalesOrder.Where(o => o.SalesOrderId == salesOrderId).FirstOrDefault();
    //Insert into my view model here
    CreatedBy = salesOrder.GetCreator();
}
```

There are of course entirely different ways to do the same thing, but having an Interface makes targeting via IoC, T4 scripts or other automation logic a lot simpler.